# USDZ files are black in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, metal, usdz

Whenever I attempt to view a USDZ file that I have downloaded from Apple's Quick Look [website](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/) in XCode it looks black.

I am currently using XCode Version 10.3 (10G8) and have included an image showcasing the issue.

[image]

Can someone please help me figure out what's going on? I have already deleted derived data, cleaned my project, and performed a fresh install of XCode, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is working as expected for me. Perhaps you have default lighting turned off? Try selecting the eye icon and enabling it.

[image: Viewing options in Xcode's 3D scene editor]